# Calculating average of multiple sets of data (performance issue)

Tags: python, postgresql

I have a needs to do calculation like average of selected data grouped by time rage collections.

Example:
Table which is storing data has several main columns which are:
  | time_stamp | external_id | value |

Now i want to calculate average for 20 (or more) groups of date ranges:
1) 2000-01-01 00-00-00 -> 2000-01-04 00-00-00
2) 2000-01-04 00-00-00 -> 2000-01-15 00-00-00
...

The important thing is that there are no gaps and intersections between groups so it means that first date and last date are covering full time range.

The other important thing is that in set of "date_from" to "date_to" there can be rows for outside of the collection (unneeded external_id's).

I have tried 2 approaches:
1) Execute query for each "time range" step with average function in SQL query (but i don't like that - it's consuming too much time for all queries, plus executing multiple queries sounds like not good approach)

2) I have selected all required rows (at one SQL request) and then i made loop over the results. The problem is that i have to check on each step to which "data group" current datetime belongs. This seams like a better approach (from SQL perspective) but right now i have not too good performance because of loop in the loop. I need to figure out how to avoid executing loop (checking to which group current timestamp belongs) in the main loop.

Any suggestions would be much helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Actually both approaches are nice, and both could benefit on the index on the `time_stamp` column in your database, if you have it. I will try to provide advice on them:

1. Multiple queries are not such a bad idea, your data looks to be pretty static, and you can run 20 `select avg(value) from data where time_stamp between date_from and date_to`-like queries in 20 different connections to speed up the total operation. You'll eliminate need of transferring a lot of data to your client from DB as well. The downside would be that you need to include an additional `where` condition to exclude rows with unneeded `external_id` values. This complicates the query and can slow the processing down a little if there are a lot of these values.
2. Here you could sort the data on server by `time_stamp` index before sending and then just checking if your current item is from a new data range (because of sorting you will be sure later items will be from later dates). This would reduce the inner loop to an `if` statement. I am unsure this is the bottleneck here, though. Maybe you'd like to look into streaming the results instead of waiting them all to be fetched.